# need to remove duplicated based on adjacent cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Remove Duplicated based on the adjacent cell values, with help of VBA

ID|Status

1234|Not Started - Need to be deleted

1234|Completed

3456|Completed

3456|Completed - Need to be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select which of the two methods do you prefer and try:

```
Sub Removeduplicates()

Dim Lastrow As Long

With Worksheets("sheet1")

    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Remove based on based on ID
    With .Range("A1" & ":B" & Lastrow)
        .Removeduplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    'Remove based on ID and Status
    With .Range("A1" & ":B" & Lastrow)
        .Removeduplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your sample data all you have to do is sort by the second column in a ascending order then use Remove Duplicates.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortNdedupe()

    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Header:=xlYes
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```